# mongo shard + maxSize

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongodb-3.2

I have a sharded cluster (mongo 3.2). I'm trying to set a [Maximum Storage Size for a Given Shard](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-sharded-cluster-balancer/#change-the-maximum-storage-size-for-a-given-shard), but it fails.

```
mongos> show dbs
DB_files  820.835GB
config      0.012GB
mongos> config = db.getSiblingDB("config")
config
mongos> config.shards.updateOne({ "_id": "shard0000"},{$set : { "maxSize": 4194304 }})
2016-12-21T15:47:00.467-0300 TypeError: Property 'updateOne' of object config.shards is not a function
```

So I tried something else:

```
mongos> use config
switched to db config
mongos> show collections
shards
actionlog
chunks
mongos
collections
lockpings
settings
version
locks
databases
tags
changelog
mongos> db.shards.updateOne({ "_id": "shard0000"},{$set : { "maxSize": 4194304 }})
2016-12-21T15:50:05.842-0300 TypeError: Property 'updateOne' of object config.shards is not a function
```

The shading is working, balancing, etc.

```
mongos> db.shards.find({ "_id": "shard0000"})
{ "_id" : "shard0000", "host" : "mongosh1:27017" }
mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status ---
  sharding version: {
        "_id" : 1,
        "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
        "currentVersion" : 6,
        "clusterId" : ObjectId("57cf4769b7dc19454fe95604")
} 
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "mongosh1:27017" }
        {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "mongosh2:27017" }
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "DB_files",  "primary" : "shard0000",  "partitioned" : true }
                DB_files.fs.chunks
                        shard key: { "files_id" : 1, "n" : 1 }
                        chunks: 
                                shard0001       9136
                                shard0000       9136
                        too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you are using a different shell version than the db version. That is, the output of `db.version()` (the server version) and `version()` (the shell version) should be the same.

For example:

```
mongos> db.version()
3.4.1
mongos> version()
2.6.12
mongos> config = db.getSiblingDB('config')
config
mongos> config.shards.updateOne({_id:'shard01'},{$set:{maxSize:4194304}})
2016-12-22T13:22:56.154+1100 TypeError: Property 'updateOne' of object config.shards is not a function
```

Note the identical error message to the one you're seeing. This is because `updateOne` function doesn't exist in early `mongo` shell. However, using the correct version:

```
mongos> db.version()
3.4.1
mongos> version()
3.4.1
mongos> config = db.getSiblingDB('config')
config
mongos> config.shards.updateOne({_id:'shard01'},{$set:{maxSize:4194304}})
{
  "acknowledged": true,
  "matchedCount": 1,
  "modifiedCount": 1
}
```